# How to protect media in your android from sharing?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, media, privacy

like a media file say video by any means like bluetooth or wifi. The point is i dont want someone to copy my video when phone is in their hands when i am not around?

Comment: store videos in spefic folder and encrypt them

Comment: I think this question should be posted in http://android.stackexchange.com/ because it's not really a programming question.

Comment: Are you developing some app to restrict user from sharing media file ?

Comment: how you want to do this, by programmatically or by using some application.

Comment: +DroidBoy Is there some application for that, if not can you say me the programatical solution?

Comment: @Saurabh I have updated my answer.. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this via programmatically, store your media files in a separate file and prefix your folder with a "." (dot). then folder will be invisible.

if you need more information.. i would like to help.. first try it yourself and ask for source code help

If you want some android application.. check following application from android app store

1) [Hide Something - Photo, Video](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colure.app.privacygallery&hl=en)

2) [File Hide Expert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tonado.boli.hermit.hider&hl=en)

3) [Hide Images Videos and Files](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alpha.filehider)

Comment: But it still can be sent through apps like xender, i tried it

Comment: did you try above applications

Comment: thankx for accepting..if you satisfied with the given answer.. do you mind if i ask for a upvote

Comment: im new user i need atleast 15 reps to upvote, sorry, thanks it worked